# how to get with condition in jsonpath

Tags: json, apache-camel, jsonpath

Having json, provide below:

```
[
  {
    "delta": {
      "status": {
        "old": {
          "status": "Stop"
        },
        "new": {
          "status": "Start"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

How I can get only delta which have new.status = 'Start' ?

I try to use Apache camel `choice().when().jsonpath(...)`

Why below statement isn't work ?

```
$..[?(@.delta.status.new.status=='Start')]
$..delta.status.new[?(@.status=='Start')]
```

I used jsonpath.com

Answer (score 0):

Your statements are just OK, I have tested it with [jsonpath.herokuapp](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com) and camel `jsonpath` component, for example the second one returns `{status: Start}`